# Redefined and ambiguous call to functions have array parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing

I want to see the difference between an array and an array reference parameter, and I got a redefined error and an ambiguous error. I don't see why the compiler cannot tell them:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef int arrTen[10];

void fun(int arr[]) { 
   cout << "arr[] called" << endl;
}

void fun(arrTen arr) {
   cout << "arrTen called" << endl;
   //cout << end(arr) - begin(arr) << endl;
}

void fun(arrTen &arr) {
   cout << "arrTen reference called" << endl;
   cout << end(arr) - begin(arr) << endl;
}

int main()
{
   int arr[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
   fun(arr); //ambiguous call to overloaded function

   return 0;
}
```

error message:

> ```
> Demo.cpp
> demo.cpp(24): error C2084: function 'void fun(int [])' already has a body
> demo.cpp(20): note: see previous definition of 'fun'
> demo.cpp(37): error C2668: 'fun': ambiguous call to overloaded function
> demo.cpp(29): note: could be 'void fun(arrTen (&))'
> demo.cpp(24): note: or       'void fun(int [])'
> demo.cpp(37): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int [10])'
> ```

1. It seems `fun(int arr[])` and `fun(arrTen arr)` are redefined.
   I don't know why an array point parameter equals to an array parameter.
2. when I comment out the `fun(int arr[])`, `fun(arr)` is an ambiguous call.
   Why the compiler cannot tell that I have passed a reference to `fun`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a function argument using array-syntax (with `[]`) then the compiler treats it as a *pointer*.

I.e. `void fun(int arr[])` is parsed as `void fun(int* arr)`.

That the array is a type-alias created by `typedef` doesn't matter, it will still be parsed as a pointer.

That means the function taking `int []` and `arrTen` arguments are the same.

---

As for the ambiguity both functions overloads (the one taking a pointer and the one taking a reference to `arrTen`) are equally valid and the compiler can't choose which one to call.

Answer (score 1):

These two functions

```
void fun(int arr[]) { 
   cout << "arr[] called" << endl;
}

void fun(arrTen arr) {
   cout << "arrTen called" << endl;
   //cout << end(arr) - begin(arr) << endl;
}
```

have the same type that is

```
void fun( int  *arr);
```

because a parameter having an array type is implicitly adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the element type.

So this code breaks the One Definition Rule.

To make it clear then consider these function declarations

```
void fun( int arr[100] );
void fun( int arr[10] );
void fun( int arr[1] );
void fun( int arr[] );
void fun( int *arr );
```

All they declare the same one function and all these declarations may be included in a compilation unit though they are redundant. But the function shall have only one definition.

On the other hand the compiler also can not select between two functions that accept an argument by reference or by value.

You could make one function with a constant parameter like

```
void fun( const arrTen arr) {
   cout << "arrTen called" << endl;
   //cout << end(arr) - begin(arr) << endl;
}
```

In this case the function that accepts an argument by reference will be called.

Comment: I get that array parameter will decay to an array element type pointer, but why an argument with const qualifier can accept a reference? And the end(), begin() functions cannot take arr as parameters, It seems the arr is not an aggregate object anymore.

Comment: @ZhenYang In the case when the const qualifier is added the parameter looks like a constant array but the argument is not a constant array. So the function that declares the parameter as reference is called.

Comment: @ZhenYang As for begin and end then they can not be applied to pointers.

Comment: OK, I can pass on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/,  but cannot pass using VS 2015. I think it's better not to write code like this.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays decay to pointers which is why there's ambiguity - but you *can* receive a reference to an array of 10 `int`s like this:

```
void fun(int (&arr)[10]) {
    std::cout << std::end(arr) - std::begin(arr) << "\n";
}
```

For a more generic approach, accepting arrays of any type and size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, size_t N>
void fun(T (&arr)[N]) {
    std::cout << "called with an array of " << N << " elements\n";
    std::cout << std::end(arr) - std::begin(arr) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    fun(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef int arrTen[10];

int main()
{
   int arr[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    arrTen arr1;

   return 0;
}
```

this is the print of typeid() of arr and arrTen

> (gdb)p typeid(arr))
>   could not find typeinfo symbol for 'int [10]'
>   (gdb)p typeid(arr1))
>   could not find typeinfo symbol for 'int [10]'

that mean the are the same for the compailer and that why you have the erroe